# Why fixed address assigned to DHCP server doesn't work?

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I have an Ubuntu server that runs DHCP server. DHCP server works good normally, but when I want to assign fixed IP address for my clients, it doesn't work.

My codes in dhcp server in `dhcpd.conf` look like:

```
sxalid-s -> my client name

host sxalid-s {
        hardware ethernet 08:00:27:5e:ce:d8;
        fixed-address 192.168.1.9;
}
```

My subnet declaration:

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.20;
option routers 192.168.1.0;
}
```

My `sxalid-s` client before I assign fixed address give `192.168.1.12` but now when I down that interface and up it again give again 192.168.1.12

I try `#dhclient` but it does not work! I want no more configuration except the default configuration.

Can anybody help me how solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the file `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` you can see your dhcp leases.

When you flush this file that it is empty, you should get a new ip address. Type:

```
echo -n "" >/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
```

And then again:

```
dhclient -v eth0
```

If it still doesn't work, then I think your hostname is not sent via dhcp and the dhcp-server cannot fit the host-statement for you. In the file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` there is a directive called `send host-name`:

```
user@host:~# grep "send host-name" /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
send host-name "<hostname>";
```

In my case it's disabled. Enter your hostname in this statement to enable `dhclient` to send the host-name within the dhcp-request:

```
send host-name "sxalid-s";
```

If it still doesn't work,  please add the contents of /var/log/syslog (of the dhcp-server) during the dhcp request to your question.

Comment: don't work. but finally I reboot server and now work properly.

Comment: It worked for me. I must have removed the `dhclient.leases` file. Restarting the service created that file but it was unable to lease ips. The second command did the trick. Thank you